# Person with role of overseen sound post production in documentaries referred to as a "supervising sound editor"?

Tags: sound, documentary, editor

I am wondering if the person with the role of overseen the sound post production and its crew (if any) in documentaries is referred to as a "supervising sound editor"? I've searched some documentaries in IMDB and most don't have someone with the "supervising sound editor" credit, they mostly have "sound re-recording mixer" and "sound" credits.

I've been in charge of documentaries' sound and credited myself as a "supervising sound editor", but now I'm wondering if I shouldn't, based on industry standards.

Thanks!